# ERROR: Does not contain source for Thread.class - Class File Editor

Tags: java, eclipse

First time post, long time watcher. Can't wait for my classmates to read this (they use the site too)

I am using Eclipse Juno w/ Java SE 1.7

I am having an eclipse problem. It doesn't happen all the time, typically only during File IO. I'm using my debugger perspective in Eclipse to try and trouble shoot some problems (its really a simple program).

UPDATE: Apparently new users are not allowed to upload screen shots. If you could take the time to click on the link to witness my problem I would appreciate it.
Screen Shot Link (not java code):

imgur.com/5IxI3.png

As you can see I am getting an odd thread.class problem. I have even reinstalled java. Could it be something with my code as well then?

Thanks for anyone who offers input or helps in anyway. I do have about a week before this is do so I'm not just looking for free answers, just frustrated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to attach source because Thread is API class.

Download Java source (not binary exe file) from Oracle

> Go to eclipse Yourproject --> Properties --> Java Build Path >
>   Libraries and expand JRE System Library --> jre version--> rt.jar.
>   Select Source attachment ---> Point to the down loaded source.

Read this [tutorial](http://www.cavdar.net/2008/07/14/3-ways-of-jdk-source-code-attachment-in-eclipse/) for more info.

Comment: **Thank You** so much. I am mobile right now but I will be trying this soon. I appreciate your feedback.